# media query in css is responding weird

Tags: css

I have a media query in my code:

```
@media (max-width: 750px) {
```

It's set at 750px, so when less than that something happens (a div changes colour, to test this)

Now when I resize my browser with Google Chrome's "Inspect" opened, the div changes colour at 938px instead of 750px

What can cause this?

[image]
[image]

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xjn0r6ff/)

Comment: Do you have screenshots and exact CSS? That might be useful...

Comment: added to jsfiddle @MyUser

Comment: I would suggest trying with Firefox CTRL-SHIFT-M instead, just to make sure. Also, have you tried simply "@media (max-width:750px) {" without the screen?

Comment: And it works fine in JSFiddle...

Comment: @MyUser yeah I tried without the screen, I put the screen in after I posted here to check if maybe that would sort it out. Also I just tried that now (ctrl+shift+m) in firefox and it seems to be working fine in firefox, it changes when it goes under 750px... i wonder why chrome is adding pixels..

Comment: Weird. Like I always say, Firefox is the best but that doesn't really help as most of the world uses Chrome... I'm afraid you'll have to work it out yourself. I hope that the things I pointed out will help. Good luck!

Comment: @MyUser thank you :)